# JsQRScanner in webview android not working

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

if i run in chrome, camera is working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDROd.jpg)

but if i run with webview in android studio, camera is not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcqAa.jpg)

I have enabled camera permission[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws1J8.jpg)

i used JsQrScanner for scan qrcode.

MainActivity.class

```
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.loadUrl("https://myurl");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        }

    });
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: Do you want to show camera in a html file that loaded in WebView?

Comment: are you shure that your APP have this permission acquired? at first your app must have access to camera, then it can share with own components like `WebView`. try to enable this permission in system settings of your app. [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) you have some doc about requesting permissions

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: I have activated camera permissions as shown in the picture I uploaded